# Long value showing default as 0

Tags: c#, wpf, string, xaml, string-formatting

I have created a WPF textbox and set a binding with a long value `PhoneNumber`.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PhoneNumber,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,StringFormat={}{0:000-000-0000},TargetNullValue=''}" MaxLength="10"></TextBox>
```

While running the textbox shows defaultvalue as 000-000-0000. But I need it as empty. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1)Instead of using long type, you can use `long?` type, which means the long variable can be null.

2) you can use string and convert the long to string. When you don't have any data in the variable you can put `string.Empty`.

Comment: first option was the one I am looking for. But it is setting to 000-000-0000 when I enter backspace

Comment: i didn't understand, what do you mean by "enter backspace"?

Comment: I this case you can assign a null into the variable.